# Nodered-OPC-UA-Siemens S7: why is my payload "0" when writing to my DB

Tags: node-red, opc-ua, siemens

I am using nodered as GUI for my S7-1500 application. They communicate using OPC-UA.
I was already successful with sending booleans and Integers to the PLC and back to my nodered-gui.
Now I have a special case, which for some reason doesn´t work:

[image: This is where i want to write Data]

So I set up my flow like this:

```
[{"id":"26ac6c0185fdca6b","type":"OpcUa-Client","z":"6a150d561d4e6972","endpoint":"e00e2f355739f286","action":"write","deadbandtype":"a","deadbandvalue":1,"time":10,"timeUnit":"s","certificate":"n","localfile":"","localkeyfile":"","securitymode":"None","securitypolicy":"None","name":"CounterUpdate","x":3820,"y":2980,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"b11b819bfd0ff6eb","type":"inject","z":"6a150d561d4e6972","name":"topic_ToolNr","props":[{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":"1","topic":"ns=3,s=\"RW_RFID_MASTER\".\"THIS\"[0].\"Wr_UserData0\";datatype=Int64","payloadType":"str","x":3350,"y":2980,"wires":[["c6a3daf80f47f7c6"]]},{"id":"c6a3daf80f47f7c6","type":"ui_text_input","z":"6a150d561d4e6972","name":"","label":"input_tool_nr","tooltip":"","group":"094a689fb04d37e6","order":2,"width":"6","height":"1","passthru":false,"mode":"number","delay":300,"topic":"topic","sendOnBlur":true,"className":"","topicType":"msg","x":3570,"y":2980,"wires":[["26ac6c0185fdca6b"]]},{"id":"e00e2f355739f286","type":"OpcUa-Endpoint","endpoint":"opc.tcp://172.16.200.170:4840","secpol":"None","secmode":"None","login":false},{"id":"094a689fb04d37e6","type":"ui_group","name":"RFID manuell Beschreiben","tab":"b39f2e7397635000","order":1,"disp":true,"width":"6","collapse":false,"className":""},{"id":"b39f2e7397635000","type":"ui_tab","name":"Service","icon":"mi-settings","order":4,"disabled":false,"hidden":false}]
```

The problem here is, that whatever I put as value in the textbox, results in sending "0" to this value on the PLC.

What am I missing here?